# Non-Hermitian Lagrangian in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity, effective-field-theory

I have seen more than once non-Hermitian Lagrangian densities being used in effective field theories. Usually the problem of unitarity is explained away with decays into some degree of freedom not included in the theory.

Does anyone knows where can I find a proper discussion of this? (Or give one if it is trivial enough?)

To be more precise: I´m looking for proof that unitarity is broken in the right direction (e.g., decay probability in all channels be smaller than one). Or better yet: an example of a UV complete theory that, once some modes are integrated out, leads to non-Hermitian Lagrangian densities.